# What is the general speed of Amazon S3 Select on a JSON file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am looking to consider S3 as a backup storage to a primary Redis DB.

I would like to be able to archive data out from Redis and into S3 which is rarely used. This however brings up the question of how quick is an S3 select? Is it quick enough for example to respond to a post request on Apache?

The data I would be looking to store is JSON files containing 5 or 6 values for each minute of the day so the file is unlikely to be larger than a few meg and will consist of 1440 objects (1 per minute of the day). Can anyone share their experience with the latency on a select against data like this?

I am getting a test setup done for it now but didn't want to bury time if the response times are routinely 5 seconds for example.

Comment: The best would be for you to check it. It depends on size of data, complexity of query and more.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I did intend to I just wondered if there was perhaps a minimum spin up time for example which would mean any query is say 3s + (complexity and size calculation)